# text-transform doesn't work with post form submit php

Tags: php, html, inline-styles

I have an input which I added the uppercase style for it as shown below:

```
style="text-transform: uppercase"
```

However, the text is not sent as upper via the post (after pressing the submit button) as shown below:

```
$_POST['_mytext']
```

I can use the upper case function in php, but I am wondering why the post is not getting the correct uppercase for the value? Is there is anything wrong with my html?

Comment: This is correct, because CSS only styles what you are looking at, not what is exactly there. You should use the strtoupper() function if you wish the real data coming in to be uppercase.

Comment: `style`/css only changes the presentation/display of the value, and not change the actual value. If you want to change the actual value, you either need to use JavaScript before posting or php after submit.

Comment: Think of CSS as window dressing ;) Just because the text in the input is bold, pink, uppercase, and including a graphic of a magnifying glass... doesnt mean the POST value coming into php will have all that formatting too.

Comment: is there a way to be done in the input properties?

Comment: Yes as @Sean mentioned ... JavaScript. And easier with jquery. But is there a reason why not in PHP? Seems a better way to ensure integrity, than to rely on whats coming from a submit.

Answer (score 3):

Styling is purely visual.

Here is an ultra-simple [demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/921fubhs/1/).

```
<span style="text-transform: uppercase">test</span>
```

In this case, `TEST` is printed to screen in accordance with the styling.

However, if you inspect the element, the source code will still read `test`.

Furthermore...

If you run the following javascript conditionals:

```
if(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=='test'){
   alert('lowercase');
}
if(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=='TEST'){
   alert('UPPERCASE');
}
```

You will only see the `lowercase` alert.  This is because the actual data isn't changed.

Comment: A better answer than Shepherd's and less likely to be a sock-puppet answer. 1+

Comment: I didn't bother explaining the php way to fix it because the @SMH already acknowledged this.  I answered the question that the OP asked.  If processing submitted user data, javascript is insecure anyway.  Oh well.  Thanks for the upvote.